# Convert .xyz to .dxf in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dxf, xyz

I am new to all of this and I would like to know if it is possible to convert .xyz to .dxf in QGIS? I heard that it is possible in ArcGIS but I am not sure about it in QGIS. (I hope I am right asuming that an Ascii file is .xyz?)
My problem is that I have to convert a digital terrain model (DGM in German) to .dxf but  I have actually no idea how to do it and how it should look like. 
When I just open it, I get the following image (and my computer gets pretty slow...):
[image]

I saw that I can save it as .tiff, but there are no more options to choose from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.xyz is a raster format, while .dxf is a vector format. Since your data is digital elevation, I assume you want contour lines in your .dxf file.

So you have to run `Raster -> Extraction -> Contour`, selecting an output filename and `Autocad DXF` file format, and a suitable contour interval.

Unfortuantely, the module always creates a shapefile output. So you have to click on the pencil next to the large input box above the `OK` button, and enter `-f DXF` before the filenames to get the desired format.

You need to activate the `Attribute name` to get elevation information as a line attribute.

See https://hub.qgis.org/issues/6695 and https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13068 for those caveats.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where do you mean that I have to enter -f DXF? I just choosed the output file format as Autocad DXF and now when I look in the properties the layer source shows .dxf. Is that also right?

Comment: And is it normal that there is no information? I mean in the attribute list? It’s the first time that I see something like this, so I have no idea if its right and you have to introduce it manually now or not...

Comment: Did you get a DXF file or a folder containing dbf/prj/shp/shx? The second would be a shapefile, with little use in CAD software. You need to activate the `Attribute name` to get elevation information as a line attribute.

Comment: You are right. I got a folder containing dbf/prj/shp/shx. So I tried it again as you said and this time I got a DXF folder. Now I will try to get the elevation information as well! Thanks a lot for your help!